# How to set up a job to restart a server when an error occurs

Tags: events, server, task, auto

I am trying to see if there is a way to set up an automatic job that runs whenever there is a certain error within the server occurs. So for an example, whenever an event ID 7001 occurs, a notification email should be sent out and the server should be restarted. I was able to set up a task job so that a notification email would be sent out, but how do I set up a job to restart the server, right after the notification is sent out?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a physical server then you can call a simple script restarting your server from the code that you used for sending email (I suppose it was also a script or some kind of program you wrote).
E.g. if you have a Windows server, than you could simply call a Batch 'script':

```
shutdown -r
```

Or if you use a Linux/Unix server, then you could call a Bash 'script' command:

```
reboot
```

You can call it right after the code sending the email.